# Make uibootstrap navbar usable when there is an active modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a workaround for making the uibootstrap navbar usable when there is an active modal on the screen?

This is a typical navbar + modal in bootstrap 3:

[image: Typical navbar and modal]

As you can see, the menu is not usable when the modal is present.

This is what I'd like:

[image: Desired behavior for navbar and modal]

I can modify the modal's top margin (from 30px to 70px) and the navbar z-index so that it is in top of the backdrop, but...

**Is there an official solution to this? how can I make the dropdowns usable? because modifying the z-index doesn't fix it.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the top position of the modal backdrop (class name is `.modal-backdrop`), not the modal itself. It's an immediate child of the body tag (in most cases). The modal backdrop is what actually covers the rest of the page.

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
   top: 70px; // however much space you need for header
}
```

And, yes, this is the way to do it. [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) also allows you to define a custom window template where you can go crazy and make as many changes as you want.